# How to implement multiple row dragging in ag-grid (angular)

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular, angular-cdk

Am able to use cdk-drag with cellRendering and implement single drag and drop. I would like to implement multiple drag and drop. Is there any way to implement multiple rows drag and drop with ag-grid? If so please provide me with an example or suggest me with the better solution.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service, so could you please share your [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or update your question with other efforts you made

Answer (score 1):

If you are using smaller version than ag-grid 23 than it does not provide feature of multi-row dragging on lesser version of ag-grid.

In ag-grid 24, you can implement by adding `[enableMultiRowDragging] = "true"` and `rowSelection='multiple'` but you also have to mention `[pagination]="false"` because it does not work with `[pagination]="true"`

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

It is possible to drag multiple rows at the same time, when `enableMultiRowDragging` is set to `true` in the gridOptions and it is combined with `rowSelection='multiple'`, and `rowDragManaged=true`.

Source: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-dragging/